# Error whilst updating from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, 21.04

I get the following error when trying to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04:

```
A problem occurred during the update.
This is usually some sort of network problem,
please check your network connection and retry
```

I have perfect internet connection. But why does this error occur?

Comment: It's no longer possible to upgrade from 20.10 the normal way because 20.10 **is out of support**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).  Standard releases come out every 6 months and are supported for 9 months after release.  Once support ends, the upgrade path can become more challenging because the old release no longer gets updates.  If you do not want to have to upgrade every 6-9 months, use an LTS release which are supported for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Server and 3 years for other flavors.

Comment: You'll need to explore your main.log, apt.log & other files (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUpdateManager maybe helpful) to see reasons, however (1) did you ensure your *groovy* or 20.10 system was fully upgraded before you tried to *release-upgrade* as that is essential and (2) with repositories moved did you change your sources to point at the old-releases site?  (removing country codes etc as you've missed the EOL window); see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  If it's a desktop system, theeasiest fix is *upgrade via re-install* which won't user files etc if you don't format